# Telegram stopped loading on BQ Aquaris E5 HD

Tags: phone

I have been using Telegram on my BQ Aquaris E5 HD since I have had it and all has been working OK.

After an update I now get notifications that I have a new messages (all OK). However, when I try to open the new message (or even existing messages) the Telegram screen looks like it is loading. However, Telegram then closes down and the original screen (I was on) then opens. So Telegram opens up and then closes down straight away.

I have uninstantiated Telegram and installed it again, but this has not helped.

Has anyone come across this and do you know how I can get Telegram to work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a known issue, some users reported experiencing this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/telegram-app/+bug/1553279). Try this solution:

> WARNING: Your secret chats (if any) will be gone forever.

1. Uninstall the app
2. Delete all the directories which look like `./home/phablet/cache/QML/Apps/com.ubuntu.telegram_x.x.x.x` (x.x.x.x. = 2.0.4.0, 2.0.8.0 etc.)
3. Delete the folder `.config/com.ubuntu.telegram`
4. Reinstall the app and register once again

Comment: Before deleting, please save a copy of the config file and upload to the comment section of the aforementioned bug. Developers need to have a look at it to fix this issue.

Comment: Do agree that the developers need to fix this issue though as an update that breaks the app is not good at all.